# contact form 7 captcha support anyother captcha plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, plugin-recommendation

I am Using Wordpress. I installed Contact form7.Now I Want To Add Captcha with Contact form7.I Don't like "Really Simple Captcha" because it shows very simple images.Any other Captcha Plugin Support Contact form7?

I Need Like the output of  "**SI CAPTCHA Anti-Spam"** or "Fast Secure Contact Form",Here Unfortunately I can't Remove Contact form7 Plugin.So I Want to Add Captcha Plugin with my Contact form7.Please Help Me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reCAPTCHA with contact form 7.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7-recaptcha-extension/

Comment: Excellent Brady.This Only I Need.Thank you very much for your Answer...:)

Comment: Note - reCaptcha will work ok if you have max one form per page. That is probably how the most sites do it. But if you happen to have two or more contact forms on a single page, only the first reCaptcha works. Oh my am I angry with them right now!!